# Android Fragment replace onClick as well as the selected tab to be change

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a `MainActivity` which has `AppBar` containing toolbar and `TabLayout`, and also `ViewPager`.

`MainActivity` holds 4 fragments home, cash, card and account.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    Window window;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        window = this.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green_dark));
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Example Wallet");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tab " + position + " Onpage Selected " + viewPager.getCurrentItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (position == 0) {
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green_dark));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green_dark));
                    }
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    }
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_yellow));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_yellow_dark));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_yellow_dark));
                    }
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_red));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_red_dark));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_red_dark));
                    }
                } else {
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green_dark));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_green_dark));
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if (fab1 != null) {
            fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);
                    startActivity(registerIntent);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new FragmentMain(), "Home");
        adapter.addFrag(new FragmentCash(), "Cash");
        adapter.addFrag(new FragmentCard(), "Card");
        adapter.addFrag(new FragmentAccount(), "Account");
        adapter.addFrag(PartThreeFragment.createInstance(20), "Tab1");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            // return null to display only the icon
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

home fragment code

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {
    private List<Movie> movieList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Movie> movieList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView,recyclerView1;
    private MovieAdapter mAdapter1,mAdapter2;
    private LinearLayout cash_layout,card_layout,account_layout;
    private ViewGroup c;

    public FragmentMain() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
        //final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        //c=container;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        cash_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_cash_bal);
        card_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_card_bal);
        account_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_account_bal);

        mAdapter1 = new MovieAdapter(movieList1);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
        prepareMovieData1();

        cash_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getContext().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
                /*actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(1));
                FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.content_cash, (Fragment)new FragmentCash()).commit();
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                //ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();*/
                /*FragmentCash fragment2 = new FragmentCash();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();*/
            }
        });

        /*mAdapter2 = new MovieAdapter(movieList2);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);
        recyclerView1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
        prepareMovieData2();*/
        return v;
    }

    private void prepareMovieData1() {
        movieList1.clear();
        Movie movie = new Movie("info","List is empty", "To create an item, click on (+) button", "","");
        movieList1.add(movie);
        mAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*public void onClick1(View v) {
        FragmentCash fragment2 = new FragmentCash();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }*/

    /*private void prepareMovieData2() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("card","Card", "New Dress", "Rs.50.00","11/09/2016");
        movieList2.add(movie);
        mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }*/
}
```

I am trying to call cash, card and account fragment from home fragment but this code

```
cash_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentCash fragment2 = new FragmentCash();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

adds other fragment with home fragment visible.

The solution I need is, in the below image when I click the cash balance it slide to the cash tab with cash fragment onscreen.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add the cash fragment on top of the view pager, or replace it all together. Instead of replacing it in the current view, I'm assuming you would like to navigate to it within the viewPager.

To do that, replace all of your onClick code with `pager.setCurrentItem(//Page number with cash fragment on it)`

So, your `onClick` would look something like this:

```
cash_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(//Your desired page number as int);
        }
    });
```

Or you could solve this easily with an interface.

Just create an interface to access your viewPager's operations like so.

```
public interface ViewPagerInterface {
    ViewPager getViewPager();
}
```

Have your activity implement it:

```
public MainActivity extends AppCompatActvity implements ViewPagerInterface {

    @Override
    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return this.viewPager;
    }
}
```

Then pass that interface to your Fragments and call the getViewPager method.

`viewPagerInterface.getViewPager().setCurrentItem(<my-int>);`

Comment: Well thanks for help @Weava but i got a solution. `TabLayout tabhost = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
                tabhost.getTabAt(1).select();`